# Multiple selections in jQuery/Cheerio

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, cheerio

I am writing a scraper, and I need it to exclude the first child and the 7th child. I can select either with not(:first-child) and not(:nth-child(7)). Is there an and operator (similar to the comma for or) in JQuery or Cheerio. Due to the nature of this scraper, I can't use De Morgan's Law

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put those together:

```
$('li:not(:first-child):not(:nth-child(7)')
```